# WP_Query custom post types one by one

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have two post types.

```
<?php  
$args = [ 
         'post_type' => ['type1', 'type2'], 
         'orderby' => ['type' => 'ASC']
        ];

$query = new WP_Query($args); ?>
```

So, I need to show type1 posts and below them type2 posts. My code shows them in random order. Where is my mistake?

Comment: What wordpress version you are using?

Comment: Also, can you share how you loop through query results?

Comment: Wordpress 5.3.1  if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();

Comment: You could always just do 2 separate loops / queries.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this inside the file and using the `$query` to loop through items:

```
if ($query->have_posts()): 
   while ($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post()
   //the rest of the loop here
```

If you can not add this query inside your template then you need to use a filter to intercept the query:

```
add_filter( 'posts_orderby' , 'order_by_type_func' );
function order_by_type_func( $orderby ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $table = $wpdb->prefix.'posts';

    if(!is_admin()){
        $orderby = $table.".post_type ASC"; 
    }
    return $orderby;
}
```

And then in your tempate run a normal query.

Comment: I made mistake in my comment above. Loop is the same as you show

Comment: Then try to use the second option. Remember to add the code in functions.php

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use an array in the "post_type" line of the arguments and for the arguments in general, use round brackets (instead of square ones) and keep `orderby` and `order` in separate lines as follows:

```
$args = array( 
  'post_type' => array('type1', 'type2'), 
  'orderby' => 'type',
  'order' => 'ASC',
);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple way to do this using the post object so you can put items exactly where you want them.  Like so:

```
<?php
$args = [ 
         'post_type' => ['type1', 'type2'], 
         'orderby' => ['type' => 'ASC']
        ];

$posts = new WP_Query($args);
?>

<div class="container-div">

<?php 
while ($posts->have_posts()) {
$posts->the_post(); 


if ($post->post_type === 'type1') { ?>

  <div class="post-type-1">

     <?php the_title(); // or whatever info you want here ?>

  </div>

<?php } else { ?>

  <div class="post-type-2">

     <?php the_title(); // or whatever info you want here ?> 

  </div>

<?php } ?>

</div>
```